# Drag start not selecting correct element

Tags: javascript, html

The dragstart event is not referencing all elements that are in the array draggables. I am wondering if it is a problem with the forEach loop, but I'm not sure. Dragging from the sidebar into the containers works just as intended, but when trying to drag the item from container to container, the dragstart event doesn't even pick up the existence of the item, only the dragover event notices anything.

I've tried pushing each new clone to the array, but even that doesn't work. I've spent like 3 hours on this one problem, and I just cannot figure it out as this is my first javascript project (I'm learning js without a tutorial).

```js
let draggables = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".left-item"));
const droppables = document.querySelectorAll(".web-prev>div");

var draggedItem;

draggables.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("dragstart", () => {
    if(item.parentElement.classList.contains("left-side")) {
      draggedItem = item.cloneNode(true);
    } else {
      draggedItem = item;
    }
    draggedItem.classList.add("is-dragging");
    draggables.push(draggedItem);
    console.log(draggables);
  });

  item.addEventListener("dragend", () => {
    draggedItem.classList.remove("is-dragging");
  });
});

droppables.forEach((zone, i) => {
  zone.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const bottomItem = insertAboveItem(zone, e.clientY);

    if (!bottomItem) {
      zone.appendChild(draggedItem);
    } else {
      zone.insertBefore(draggedItem, bottomItem);
    }
  });
});

const insertAboveItem = (zone, mouseY) => {
  const nonDragging = zone.querySelectorAll(".left-item:not(.is-dragging)");

  let closestItem = null;
  let closestOffset = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

  nonDragging.forEach((item) => {
    const { top } = item.getBoundingClientRect();

    const offset = mouseY - top;

    if (offset < 0 && offset > closestOffset) {
      closestOffset = offset;
      closestItem = item;
    }
  });

  return closestItem;
};
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.left-side {
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  width:150px;
  border-right:2px solid black;
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction:column;
  gap:7px;
  padding:7px;
}

.left-item {
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background:lightgrey;
  border-radius:5px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.web-prev {
  position:absolute;
  left:150px;
  width:calc(100% - 150px);
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction:column;
  padding:7px;
  gap:7px;
}

.web-prev>div {
  width:100%;
  min-height:min(20%, 150px);
  background:lightcoral;
  padding:0 7px;
}

.web-prev>div * {
  margin:7px 0;
}

.left-item.is-dragging {
  opacity:.7;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-side">
  <div class="left-item a" draggable="true">a</div>
  <div class="left-item b" draggable="true">b</div>
  <div class="left-item c" draggable="true">c</div>
  <div class="left-item d" draggable="true">d</div>
  <div class="left-item e" draggable="true">e</div>
</div>
<div class="web-prev">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by putting the addEventListener in a function and calling it every time I create a new object. I didn't know at the time that event listeners are not copied by cloneNode(true).

```js
function addEvents (draggables) {
  draggables.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("dragstart", () => {
      if(item.parentElement.classList.contains("left-side")) {
        draggedItem = item.cloneNode(true);
        draggables.push(draggedItem)
        addEvents(draggables);
      } else {
        draggedItem = item;
      }
      draggedItem.classList.add("is-dragging");
      console.log(draggables);
    });

    item.addEventListener("dragend", () => {
      draggedItem.classList.remove("is-dragging");
    });
  });
}
```